# Equivalence relation induced by $f$ and basic algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

First part goes to the second topic, basic algebra.

Given a function $f: A \subset \mathbb{R} \to B$, that it's not injective, and let $x_1 , x_2 \in A$. Find a function $g: A \to A$, $g(x_2) = x_1$ such as, $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1 = g(x_2)$.

Otherwise, I just want to find the relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ such as $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. The trivial relation it's $x_1 = x_2$, Don't consider it.

For example 
$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; f(x) = x^2$ and $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
$$f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1^2 = x_2^2 \Rightarrow x_1 = \sqrt{x_2^2} \Rightarrow$$
$$ \Rightarrow x_1 = |x_2| \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2 \mbox{ or } x_1 = - x_2$$
So we can write: $g(x_2) = - x_2 $

Making a link to Equivalence relations.

Given an equivalence relation in $A$, that it's induced by $f$;

$(x_1 \sim x_2$ if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$), I'll define $\overline{x} = \{ a \in A | a \sim x\}$ as the equivalence class of $x \in A$.

I) So can I claim that $\overline{x} = \{x, g(x)\} \mbox{ , } \forall x \in A$?

Remember that $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and i'm ignoring the trivial relation $g(x_2) = x_2$.

II) Is this a good method to find $\overline{x}$? I guess not. I've tried for $f(x) = x^2 - 5x +6$, and I know anything about the case $A \subset R^n, n > 1$.

OBS: Please, don't tell me the usual method to find $\overline{x}$. I'll try this, if I get none, I'll make another question here.

Comment: You should be careful with quantifiers when writing your question. I honestly can't understand what you mean. In particular the phrase "Find a function $g:A\to A$. $g(x_2)=x_1$ such as, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1=g(x_2)$" does not make sense. Maybe try to write the problem as you have it? (Say, copy it from your textbook, and reference where it comes from?)

Comment: well i knew that this part would cause some trouble. I'll think a little bit more in the question, then i will write the problem as it was shown to me, later. Thanks.